# DCount() In VBA Always Returning A Null Value

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013, dcount

I am attempting to use the DCount() Function to return a count from my table.  My issue is that it always returns a NULL value.

How should I Re-write this VBA statement so that it returns the accurate count?

```
ReturnedCount = DCount("CountOfItems", "[__TestTable]", "NameOfItem = " & ItemName)
Debug.Print ReturnedCount
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NameOfItem` implies a string.  You need to wrap strings in single quotes when passing them as a parameter to a D-Function; just like passing them as a parameter in a Query.

> ReturnedCount = DCount("CountOfItems", "[__TestTable]", "NameOfItem = '" & ItemName & "'")

Using the immediate window to test your D-Functions will simplify debugging.

[image]

Comment: That gives me a compile error - expected expression error

Comment: I was missing a double quote.

Comment: When I step through the code and I use a Debug.Print ReturnedCount it is Empty - and if it matters CountOfItems is a Number and NameOfItem is a shortttext

Comment: `DCount` will return 0 but never returns empty.  Likewise if `ReturnedCount`  was properly typed (e.g. Dim ReturnedCount As Long) then it would not return empty.

Comment: Is there a way to have it return 0 if NULL?  And turns out DSUM() is what I was after as well ,not the DCount()

Comment: I don't think that the D-Functions can return null.  In any case, [Nz Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa172237(v=office.11).aspx) is used in Access to return a differenct value when null.  (e.g. NZ(Value,0) returns 0 if Value is null)

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
On Error Goto 0
ReturnedCount = DCount("*", "[__TestTable]", "NameOfItem = '" & ItemName & "'")
```

It will at least return 0 (zero) ... if the table and field names are correct.

Comment: That is not possible, except if you have error handling. Remove that - see edit.